# Why are my icons changing colours in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to have icons in a navigation drawer for my app in android studio and they keep on becoming grey when I have them as a different color.

I tried to use colored PNG files imported as drawables and they get turned grey in the app. I've tried to use the android studio clipart icons and set the color I want but they still are grey in the app.

I presume this is some issue with my styling/themes but I don't know how to fix this.

How do I get these icons to stay as the color I want?

**colored PNG files**

[image: colored PNG files]

**grey in the app**

[image: grey in the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this line in your activity_main.xml:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/my_desired_colour"
```

to NavigationView (it is located in activity_main.xml layout file) The default tint is black but you can use an even darker shade of black by using #000000

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line in your NavigationView tag in xml file -

```
 app:itemIconTint="@color/custom_color"
```